# How to inject Webpack DefinePlugin variables in non Module Scripts

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, webpack-4

I have the following issue:

I'm using the *DefinePlugin* to define some variables across .js modules. This is working fine in .js modules

However, **my multi page application loads** a local script (*custom.js*) inside a `<HEADER>` TAG. This script is standard javascript (not a module), using one of the variables defined in DefinePlugin. It's a .js that must be loaded in every page of the App.

For some reason this variable WEB_CONTEXT is not being interpolated by Webpack on BUILD process.

I assume that the reason is that as it is not recognized as a dependency.

**Webpack config.js:**

```
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'WEB_CONTEXT': 'myapp/main'   
    );
```

The global script is loaded like this:

`<script src="./src/js/custom.js"></script>`

**custom.js**

```
 $(function () {

     // Compiled file incorrectly shows:
        const myPath = `${WEB_CONTEXT}/resources/images`;

     // Instead of:
        const myPath = `myapp/main/resources/images`;

    });
});
```

**Question is:**
Is there anyway with Webpack to make WEB_CONTEXT variable available ALSO for those scripts like custom.js (not imported, but loaded via ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack "works" only on files that are part of the dependency tree that starts from the entry file.

If your `custom.js` file is not inside this tree, webpack **won't** touch it.

You can add it by require it, or add it as additional entry to your app.

```
//webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './path/to/my/entry/file.js',
    custom: './path/to/custom.js'
  }
};
```

Comment: I did something similar to what you mention and works ok (posted below). 

Also needed to add the chunk to each page in the app
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**webpack.config.js**

```
entry : {
    main: './path/to/my/entry/file.js',
    custom: './path/to/custom.js'
}
```

And the in the plugins section:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: `./${ruta}`,
                inject: true,
                chunks: ['main', 'custom'], // <-Added custom chunk here.
                filename: `${fileName}.html`,
                templateParameters: {
                    WEB_CONTEXT: basePath
                  }
              });
```